# Simple concurrency in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

I have a small PHP function on my website which basically does 3 things:

- check if user is logged in
- if yes, check if he has the right to do this action (DB Select)
- if yes, do the related action (DB Insert/Update)

If I have several users connected at the same time on my website that try to access this specific function, is there any possibility of concurrency problem, like we can have in Java for example? I've seen some examples about semaphore or native PHP synchronization, but is it relevant for this case?

My PHP code is below:

```
if ( user is logged ) {
    sql execution : "SELECT....."
    if(sql select give no results){
        sql execution : "INSERT....."
    }else if(sql select give 1 result){
        if(selected column from result is >= 1){
           sql execution : "UPDATE....."
        }
    }else{
        nothing here....
    }
}else{
   nothing important here...
}
```

Comment: No. MySQL takes care for you.

Comment: What exatly is the DB function? MySql has different locking mechanisms depending on table type

Comment: `START TRANSACTION;`

Comment: I think it'd help if you show the full SQL of each of your three queries. (In particular is the UPDATE incrementing a counter, or setting a text field.)

Answer (score 0):

Not in PHP. But you might have users inserting or updating the same content.
You have to make shure this does not happen.

So if you have them update their user profile only the user can access. No collision will occur.

BUT if they are editing content like in a Content-Management System... they can overwrite each others edits. Then you have to implement some locking mechanism.

For example(there are a lot of ways...) if you write an update on the content keeping the current time and user.
Then the user has a lock on the content for maybe 10 min. You should show the (in this case) 10 min countdown in the frontend to the user. And a cancel button to unlock the content  and ... you probably get the idea

If another person tries to load the content in those 10 min .. it gets an error. "user xy is already... lock expires at xx:xx"

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's the point: how to make sure that the users won't be "mixed up" inside this same function?

Comment: edited my answer to clarify the "make shure this does not happen" part

Answer (score 0):

Each user who accesses your website is running a dedicated PHP process. So, you do not need semaphores or anything like that. Taking care of the simultaneous access issues is your database's problem.

Comment: There's 3 different buttons on my website that execute this function, each one with different parameters given to my query (an id). So even if 200 people click at the same time on theses buttons, there's no chance that the security check is failed or the params of my query are with the bad id?

Comment: Are those 200 people UPDATEing their own row in the DB table, or all (potentially) UPDATEing the same row? If 200 people all try to UPDATE the same row, what is the correct behaviour you expect (first succeeds, last succeeds, you don't care as long as one of them succeeds, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not safe to decide whether to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` based on a `SELECT` result, because a concurrent PHP process can `INSERT` the row after you executed your `SELECT` and saw no row in the table.

There are two solutions. Solution number one is to use `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. These two query types are "atomic" from perspective of your script, and solve most cases. `REPLACE` tries to insert the row, but if it hits a duplicate key it replaces the conflicting existing row with the values you provide, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a little bit more sophisticated, but is used in a similar situations. See the documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

For example, if you have a table `product_descriptions`, and want to insert a product with ID = 5 and a certain description, but if a product with ID 5 already exists, you want to update the description, then you can just execute the following query (assuming there's a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key on ID):

```sql
REPLACE INTO product_description (ID, description) VALUES(5, 'some description')
```

It will insert a new row with ID 5 if it does not exist yet, or will update the existing row with ID 5 if it already exists, which is probably exactly what you want.

If it is not, then approach number two is to use locking, like so:

```php
 query('LOCK TABLE users WRITE')
 if (num_rows('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ...')) {
      query('UPDATE users ...');
 }
 else {
      query('INSERT INTO users ...');
 }
 query('UNLOCK TABLES')
```